# Regex to check if string contains only one uppercase

Tags: java, regex

What is the regex to make sure that a given string contains exactly one uppercase letter? if the string contains more than one i dont want it to be matched.

- `just 1 Uppercase character`

I know the patterns for individual sets namely `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `\d` and `_|[^\w]` (I got them correct, didn't I?).

But how do I make them to match only with strings (in java) that only contains 1 uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 negated character classes:

```
^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$
```

Above regex will support ASCII upper case letters only. If you want to match unicode letters then use:

```
^\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FFk4Ny/2)
[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FFk4Ny/1)

Here:

- `\P{Lu}*`: Match 0 or more non-uppercase unicode letters
- `\p{Lu}`: Match an uppercase unicode letter